# TcpClient not able to read on second try

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, networkstream

I am running into a problem when I am trying to read the second time after having received once. I believe the write is queued and only goes through when I stop the application. somehow after the first read I am blocking even after reading the whole message. My goal is to read the incoming message, process it then send a message to the client that connected, then expect a message back from the client acknowledging it got the message. 
Here is the code I have so far

I start a listener on a separate thread to await clients

```
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 14000);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.listenThread.Start();
```

Then after a client has connected I throw the handling of the communication on another thread

```
        this.tcpListener.Start();
        tcpClient = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessMessage));
        clientThread.Start(tcpClient);
```

The ProcessMessage method looks like the follwing

```
public void ProcessMessage(object client)
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            tcpClient = client as TcpClient;
        }

        this.messageReceived = false;

        NetworkStream clientReadStream = tcpClient.GetStream();


        byte[] message = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int byteRead = 0;

        while (!this.messageReceived)
        {
            byteRead = 0;
            if (tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    byteRead = clientReadStream.Read(message, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                if (byteRead == 0)
                {

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                    this.request = encoder.GetString(message, 0, byteRead);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.request))
                    {
                        this.messageReceived = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After processing the message then I am required to send a message back to the client, I do that from a different thread via a method called SendData

```
 public void SendData(string data)
        {
            if (tcpClient != null)
            {

                if (tcpClient.Connected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                        NetworkStream clientWriteStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

                        byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(data);
                        clientWriteStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        clientWriteStream.Flush();

                        this.messageReceived = false;

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Not sure what direction to look.. Thank you for any suggestion or direction in advance

Comment: Is this a classic case of expecting TCP to handle _messages_? TCP guarantees that bytes pushed in one end of a connection will drop out the other end in the same order and without duplication. There is no concept of message. Have you checked your buffers to see that you haven't received more, or less, than one message at a time?

Comment: In this particular case, we are trying to communicate xml between two entities. The communication back and forth is done one stage at a time and only with one client at a time. So I can assume one call coming and nothing else will be coming until I write (send) another.

Comment: @crossroad: You misunderstood the comment. The point is that you cannot know that the xml data will arrive in a single read. It may take multiple reads to get the full xml message. I have a [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).

Comment: Just to enhance the fun, if the remote end sends more than one message then a single read may get bytes from more than one message. I generally use a message header with, at a minimum, a data length field. (Usually there are message type and subtype fields, perhaps a serial number used to correlate requests with responses, ... .) A simple state machine can manage receiving bytes from the stream and extracting headers and messages.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for the link. I'll read up.

Comment: you are setting this.messageReceived = true; when you have recive message, and while condation is while (!this.messageReceived), this is becuase when first message recived, you'r recive while will terminate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting this.messageReceived = true; when you have recive message, and while condation is while (!this.messageReceived), this is becuase when first message recived, you'r recive while will terminate...

try this code:

```
public void ProcessMessage(object client)
{
    if (client != null)
    {
        tcpClient = client as TcpClient;
    }

    this.messageReceived = false;

    NetworkStream clientReadStream = tcpClient.GetStream();


    byte[] message = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
    int byteRead = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        byteRead = 0;
        if (tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                byteRead = clientReadStream.Read(message, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            if (byteRead == 0)
            {

                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                this.request = encoder.GetString(message, 0, byteRead);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.request))
                {
                    this.messageReceived = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and be careful from this part of code :

```
   if (byteRead == 0)
   {

        break;
   }
   else ...
```

because if Read method dose not read any thing while again will terminate...